# Missing required parameter: client_id in google oauth

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC and I was trying to integrate GMAIL API to it. I am facing an issue during integration of Google OAuth. I created the client id and client secret in the Google developer console.

This is my code:

`appsettings.json`:

```js
{
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "Authentication": {
        "Google": {
            "ClientId": "my-client-id",
            "ClientSecret": "my-client-secret"
        }
    },
}
```

View markup:

```cs
<a class="btn btn-info" asp-controller="Home" 
   asp-action="GoogleAuthenticate">Test</a>
```

Controller code:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

     public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
     }

     public IActionResult Index()
     {
        return View();
     }

     public IActionResult GoogleAuthenticate()
     {
          return new ChallengeResult(
             GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
             new AuthenticationProperties
             {
                    RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleOauthCallback", "Home") 
             });
     }

     public IActionResult GoogleOauthCallback()
     {
         ViewData["LoginMessage"] = "Successfull" ;

         return View();
     }
}
```

This is my Program.cs file :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("GmailOutlookAPIContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'GmailOutlookAPIContextConnection' not found.");

var services = builder.Services;
var configuration = builder.Configuration;


services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{

    
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    
    googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    Console.WriteLine(googleOptions.ClientId); // For debugging
    Console.WriteLine(googleOptions.ClientSecret); // For debugging
});




// Add services to the container.
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication(); // Add this line to enable authentication.
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

However, when I select the google account that I want to log n, I get this error :

> Error 400: invalid_request Missing required parameter: client_id

Also, can anyone suggest documentation of integrating Google gmail API? I am beginner on this and could not find a working documentation with ASP.NET Core MVC

I've tried to follow the official documentation, but it seems to be incomplete

Comment: please post actual code of `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs`  file

Comment: Have you checked if your client_id is valid?